# Finding the volume of a cone by integration of parabolic conic sections

Tags: calculus, integration, conic-sections, volume

I am working on a purely academic way of finding the volume of a right circular cone of height $h$ and radius $r$, (assume $h > r$), using integration of parabolic conic sections (conic sections parallel to the side of the cone). The end result being the geometric equation for the volume of a cone

#### $$v=\frac{π r^{2}h}{3}$$

The part I'm having trouble with is figuring out and write the equation for the parabolas.

I know that:

- $h$ = height of the cone
- $r$ = radius of the cone,
- $s$ = side length of the cone = $\sqrt{r^{2} + h^{2}}$.

Limits of integration

---

- I found the limits of integration to be from $0$ to $D$, where $D = cos(90 - \theta)2r$. Where $\theta$ is the angle from the base (viewing the cone from the side, giving me a triangular cross section) to the side $s$ of the cone.
- I arrived at the upper limit of integration being $cos(90 - \theta)2r$ by creating a right triangle where the hypotenuse is the base $2r$, the short side is part of side $s$, and the long side is a line perpendicular to $s$, from $s$ to the opposite corner of the triangular cross section of the cone $\theta_2$.
- Using this triangle I can find the length of the perpendicular line by stating that $cos(\theta_2) = \frac {adj}{hyp}$ where $adj$ is the adjacent side of the right triangle to $\theta_2$, and $hyp$ is the hypotenuse of the right triangle
- I know that $\theta_2=180 - 90 - \theta$, therefor $\theta_2 = 90 - \theta$. I also know the base is $2r$ so I can say $cos(\theta_2) = \frac {D}{2r}$ (where $D=$the adjacent side) and as such $cos(90 - \theta)=\frac{D}{2r}$. When I rearrange this I get $D=cos(90 - \theta)2r$
- So my limits of integration would run the distance from one side of the cone to the opposite corner $D$ in other words from $0$ to $D$

Equation for the parabolas

---

$$\int_0^{D}(?)dx$$

This is the part I’m having trouble figuring out (assuming I found the limits of integration correctly). I’m not sure how to find and write the equation for the parabolas in a way that I can integrate it across the entire cone to get the volume.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: A picture would be very helpful here.

Comment: And pictures there were! These are great :) As a partial answer to your question, you would need to know the distance from the vertex of each parabola to the base of the cone, and then the inside would be the area contained inside that section of the parabola. The easy way would just to use calculus, but there are purely geometric ways of doing this: see [this post] (http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/305268/how-to-calculate-the-area-closed-by-a-parabola-and-a-line-without-calculus) for details.

Comment: Thanks! How would I go about doing it with calculus? Because I want to do it via calculus and integration, and have the end result of that be the geometric formula.

Answer (score 1):

The volume may be calculated with Cavalieri's principle and a bit of care.

Place the cone with the center of its base at the origin. For $-r \leq x \leq r$, let $A(x)$ denote the area of the parabolic cross-section "at $x$".

[image: A parabolic slice of a cone, inscribed in a rectangle]

Note that:

- The area under the parabola is two-thirds the area of the circumscribing rectangle.
- The width of the circumscribing rectangle is $2\sqrt{r^{2} - x^{2}}$.
- A longitudinal section of the cone has sides $\sqrt{r^{2} + h^{2}}$ and base $2r$, so by similar triangles the circumscribing rectangle has slant height $(r - x)\sqrt{r^{2} + h^{2}}/(2r)$.

Consequently,
$$
A(x) = \tfrac{2}{3} \cdot 2\sqrt{r^{2} - x^{2}} \cdot (r - x) \frac{\sqrt{r^{2} + h^{2}}}{2r}
  = \frac{2\sqrt{r^{2} + h^{2}}}{3r}\, \sqrt{r^{2} - x^{2}}\, (r - x).
\tag{1}
$$

Now for the bit of care: A thin planar slice meeting the cone's diameter at $x$ and $x + dx$ is tilted with respect to the $x$-axis, and by similar triangles has thickness
$$
dv = \frac{h}{\sqrt{r^{2} + h^{2}}}\, dx
\tag{2}
$$
rather than $dx$. Multiplying (1) and (2), the volume of the planar slice of cone at location $x$, with $-r \leq x \leq r$, is
$$
dV = A(x)\, dv
  = \frac{2h}{3r}\, \sqrt{r^{2} - x^{2}}\, (r - x)\, dx.
\tag{3}
$$
The volume of the cone is the integral
$$
\text{Vol}
  = \int_{-r}^{r} \frac{2h}{3r}\, \sqrt{r^{2} - x^{2}}\, (r - x)\, dx
  = \frac{2h}{3} \int_{-r}^{r} \sqrt{r^{2} - x^{2}}\, dx
  - \frac{2h}{3r} \int_{-r}^{r} x \sqrt{r^{2} - x^{2}}\, dx.
$$
The first integral is the area of a half-disk of radius $r$, namely $\frac{1}{2}\pi r^{2}$, while the second vanishes as the integral of an odd function over a symmetric interval. That is, $\text{Vol} = \frac{1}{3} \pi r^{2}h$.

Answer (score 0):

To be honest, I have no clue on how to help you or on how to get a result from your way of doing it, but have you tried the much simpler way of integrating a *solid of revolution*?

Consider a straight line in a two-dimensional coordinate system, with y-intercept $r$ and x-intercept $h$. If you rotate this straight line around the x-axis, you get your cone, and using a simple integration rule you get your formula.

Since $r$ is the y-intercept and $h$ the x-intercept, your function is: $$f(x) = -\frac{rx}{h} + r$$

Using the formula for volumes of solids of revolution, you get:

$$V = \pi \int_{0}^{h} (-\frac{rx}{h} + r)^{2}dx = \frac{\pi h r^{2}}{3}$$