# How to find the area between a quadratic function $f(x)=ax^2+b$ and a line $g(x)=c$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions, area

How to find the area between a quadratic function $f(x)=ax^2+b$ and a line $g(x)=c$?

So imagine you have the simple function $f(x)=x^2$ and the constant function $g(x)=2$ How can I find the area between the $f(x)=0$ and $f(x)=2$ without using calculous?

Comment: Without using integrals ?

Comment: Yes. Without any integration.

Comment: What do you want to use then ? Do you have a specific idea or is this an open question ?

Comment: Are you allowed to use [Archimedes' formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Quadrature_of_the_Parabola) for a segment of a parabola? Or are you supposed to duplicate this? Be aware that Archimedes' method basically uses the methods of calculus, before calculus was discovered/invented, without actually using calculus.

Comment: My initial thought is that areas under graphs are defined to be the limit of the sums of strips of rectangles and so integrating is unavoidable. I could be wrong and its an interesting question.

Comment: This is nearly a duplicate: see the question (http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/305268/how-to-calculate-the-area-closed-by-a-parabola-and-a-line-without-calculus)

Comment: Yes, thanks to all. I could not remember that it was the Archimede's formula the name of what I was trying to find. Thanks.